# How to translate de postdate format for a multilanguage site

Tags: localization, postdate, format

I have a site with 2 languages: Nl and En
Everything translates to Dutch but only the date stays in English...

I use this to get my news items:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').limit(6).find() %}
    <li>
              <p>{{ entry.title}} {{ entry.postDate.format('d M Y') }}</p>
              <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
            </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The month stays in English, how can I format de post date, with the locale I'm viewing the site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
{{ entry.postDate.format('d M Y') }}
```

Use:

```
{{ entry.postDate | date('d M Y') }}
```

That should work.